# Call a thread and call new program primeThreads.c

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-errors, pthreads, primes

So I have a program prime.c below and I'm supposed to speed it up by making each prime call a thread and call the new program primeThreads.c as such:

```
 > gcc –o prime prime.c –lm
 > time ./prime
 >gcc –o primeThreads primeThreads.c –lm –lpthread
 >time ./primeThread
```

I'm just a little confused as to how I would do this? Am I supposed to create the threads in primeThreads.c and then call it? Also how would I call this file from prime.c? I tried creating the threads in prime.c below and

```
/tmp/cc8Lo90g.o: In function `main':
prime.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
prime.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

prime.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *prime(void*);

int main() 
{
  int i;
  pthread_t t1;

  long int number[10] = {5011*5009, 1293961, 1293967, 5021*4241, 4723*5009, 
                         5011*5021, 1299173, 1160807, 4241*4723, 1161829};

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    prime(number+i);
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, prime, " ");
        pthread_join(t1, NULL);  
  } 

  return(0);
}


void *prime(void *n) {
  int i;
  long int num = *((long int *)n);
  int max = (int) sqrt(num);
  for (i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    usleep(1000);
    if (num % i == 0) {
      printf("%ld is not prime\n", num);
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  printf("%ld is prime\n", num);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses `size_t` for variables that will never be < 0
3. limits the scope of variable `i` to the enclosing `for()` statement
4. allows the compiler to determine the number of entries in the `number[]` table
5. eliminated the 'magic' number `10`
6. eliminated the delay from `usleep( 1000 )`
7. eliminated the unused header file: `unistd.h`
8. changed the `pthread_t tl` to an array so easy to use `pthread_join()` so multiple threads can exist at same time
9. inserted appropriate horizontal spacing for readability
10. Note: an indent width of 2 can be 'lost' when using variable width fonts, so changed all indent width to 4 spaces
11. Note: adding threads to a 'memory bound' program will NOT make the program faster.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *prime( void* );

int main( void ) 
{
    long int number[] = {5011*5009, 1293961, 1293967, 5021*4241, 4723*5009, 
                         5011*5021, 1299173, 1160807, 4241*4723, 1161829};

    pthread_t t1[ sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0]) ];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0])); i++) 
    {
        pthread_create( &t1[i], NULL, prime, (void*)(number+i) );  
    } 

    for( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0])); i++ )
    {
        pthread_join( t1[i], NULL ); 
    }
    return(0);
}


void *prime( void *n ) 
{
    size_t num = *((size_t *)n);
    size_t max = (size_t) sqrt((double)num);
  
    for ( size_t i = 2; i <= max; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( num % i == 0 ) 
        {
            printf( "%ld is not prime\n", num );
            pthread_exit( NULL );
        }
    }

    printf( "%ld is prime\n", num );    
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
25100099 is not prime
1293961 is prime
1293967 is prime
21294061 is not prime
1299173 is prime
25160231 is not prime
20030243 is not prime
1160807 is prime
23657507 is not prime
1161829 is prime
```